# How to check the assumption of equal error variance might be violated?

Tags: anova, assumptions, boxplot

[image]

I want use this box plot to check it.
Thank you

Comment: Do you actually have access to raw data, or are you trying to make this inference just based on the given figure?

Comment: I have the data in my computer. But now I only need use this graph.@DavidMarx

Comment: I this homework or similar? Think about what variance *is* (i.e. spread) and what feature of the boxplot shows the variance. Then look at the graph and decide. However, what model is it you want to fit or check assumption of homogeneity for? You probably want to be looking at the residuals from such a model, but possibly not. So you need to explain more.